# location of python27.dll from python itself

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the path of python27.dll from the python interpreter itself in windows.

I am looking for something like sys.executable that can get me the path to python27.dll ( just the directory ould do as well)

Answer (score 8):

You can use pywin32 to get a list of DLLs used by the python executable, then search those for python27.dll:

```
import win32process

for process in win32process.EnumProcessModules(-1):
  name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(-1, process)
  if "python27.dll" in name:
    print name
```

In the above example, -1 is the pseudo-process handle for the current process. You can also get the handle via:

```
curHandle = win32process.GetCurrentProcess()
```

pywin32 is available for download here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Comment: this says `C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll`, but there's no such file

Comment: On 64-bit Windows the 32-bit python27.dll is really in C:\Windows\sysWOW64. But if you try opening the C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll in a 32-bit process, it'll open just fine. If I'm not mistaken, WOW stands for Woodoo Of Windows. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that, python27.dll get installed at system path, you can extract the absolute path by this way:

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_call("where python27.dll")
```

output:

```
C:\Windows\System32\python27.dll
0
```