# Location of Python dylib from python itself in Mac

Tags: python, macos, cx-freeze, dylib

We can get the location of python27.dll in Windows from link [location of python27.dll from python itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053761/location-of-python27-dll-from-python-itself)

However, how to get the location of python-build-in dylib in Mac with python itself?

---

The system default python dylib is

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

Homebrew-build python dylib is :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

We use cx_Freeze to build standalone binary and need to know which python dylib is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subprocess to run the command below (**$ExecuableFilePath$** can be  /usr/local/bin/python or execuable file created from cx_Freeze):

```
otool -L $ExecuableFilePath$
```

The output path of the Python lib is the right location.